# Label propagation from a Prometheus target to an alert

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have some additional labels on *Prometheus* targets via service discovery and re-labeling, e.g. `instance_name`, or `instance_id`.
[image]

I would like to propagate those labels from a specific target to defined alerts.

I read documentation through and through and tried different configurations, like the following one, but was not able to figure out how to achieve such propagation.

```yaml
alert_relabel_configs:
- source_labels: ['__meta_oci_instance_id']
  target_label: 'instance_id'

metric_relabel_configs:
- source_labels: ['__meta_oci_instance_id']
  target_label: 'instance_id'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is use `relabel_configs` to have this label as a target label (probably the `instance` label). Then in your alerting rule be careful to not lose the label, so for example use `without` rather than `by`.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that I should preserve the needed label in the `expr` element of the _alerting rule_?

Comment: Yes, that's what you need to do.